# Custom Measure displays no data

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I have developed a very basic custom measure, but on my dashboard it keeps saying no data. Below is my sensor code:

context.newMeasure()
    .forMetric(FILENAME_SIZE)
    .withValue(20)
    .save();

Comment: Please provide more information on how the metric is defined, which API you are using, etc.

Comment: I used the sample plugin code provided :https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example and my Sonar server is 5.6.1. I see the plugins getting loaded in the logs, but when I add the new measure to custom measures it just says no data found.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the only way a measure will show up in the UI is if there is a MeasureComputer (*org.sonar.api.ce.measure.MeasureComputer*) that defines it as an "Output Metric". The "Input Metric" is the one to be used to compute the Output Metric.

For example, in the SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example (on GitHub), there are several classes that implement the MeasureComputer interface:

- *[org.sonarsource.plugins.example.measures.ComputeSizeAverage](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/plugins/example/measures/ComputeSizeAverage.java)*
- *[org.sonarsource.plugins.example.measures.ComputeSizeRating](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/plugins/example/measures/ComputeSizeRating.java)*